# Prestashop query blowing SQL

Tags: sql, prestashop

My prestashop sql is blowing after using this query:

```
SELECT
            p.id_product,  MAX(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute) id_product_attribute, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`name`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, product_shop.`id_category_default`,
            MAX(image_shop.`id_image`) id_image, il.`legend`,
            ps.`quantity` AS sales, p.`ean13`, p.`upc`, cl.`link_rewrite` AS category, p.show_price, p.available_for_order, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, p.customizable,
            IFNULL(pa.minimal_quantity, p.minimal_quantity) as minimal_quantity, stock.out_of_stock,
            product_shop.`date_add` > "2020-10-27" as new
        FROM `ps_product_sale` ps
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product` p ON ps.`id_product` = p.`id_product`
         INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop
        ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute` pa
            ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
         LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_shop product_attribute_shop
        ON (product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop = 1 AND product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1)
         LEFT 
            JOIN ps_stock_available stock
            ON (stock.id_product = p.id_product AND stock.id_product_attribute = IFNULL(`product_attribute_shop`.id_product_attribute, 0) AND stock.id_shop = 1  )
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl
            ON p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
            AND pl.`id_lang` = 7 AND pl.id_shop = 1 
        LEFT JOIN `ps_image` i ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`) LEFT JOIN ps_image_shop image_shop
        ON (image_shop.id_image = i.id_image AND image_shop.id_shop = 1 AND image_shop.cover=1)
        LEFT JOIN `ps_image_lang` il ON (i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = 7)
        LEFT JOIN `ps_category_lang` cl
            ON cl.`id_category` = product_shop.`id_category_default`
            AND cl.`id_lang` = 7 AND cl.id_shop = 1 
        WHERE product_shop.`active` = 1
        AND p.`visibility` != 'none'
        AND p.`id_product` IN (26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,.............................)
```

In the place of the dots the query puts all my 100.000 products making the query take minutes.
Any one know what is this query for or where can I find it or fix it?
Regards

Comment: What??  First off, who can even read this?  Second, what does "blowing" mean?  You should probably be writing the i_product values from the IN clause into a temp table, then join with that

Comment: by blowing I mean "Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused".

Comment: I didn't write this, this is either a prestahop native query or some module, i'm just trying to fix it

Comment: On what page this query is executed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a core query from the **ProductSale** class (getBestSalesLight method).

Comment: Thanks for the help but is it normal this part: AND p.`id_product` IN (26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,............ with 100000 products, what calls this function?